# Cordova OpenTok integration Chrome issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-chrome, firefox, opentok

I'm currently trying to develop a Cordova-based mobile application integrated with OpenTok. I am using the plugin from below:
https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok (version 1.0.3)

When I am trying to subscribe from the mobile application, to a stream published from Google Chrome web browser (version 51.0.2704.106 m), I am getting blank screen and the error from below:

```
E/OTPlugin: subscriber exception: Internal error -- WebRTC subscriber error., stream id: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-06afdb1e6504
```

Also, from Mozilla Firefox web browser (version 47.0.1), the stream that I am subscribing to, freezes every few seconds (on the mobile app).

Above, I used the terminology publish and subscribe as in the plugin documentation.

Can you help me solve those issues?

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: Please remove browser platform and add it again .

Comment: On the browser I'm running a simple web application, not a Cordova one. The Cordova application is only on mobile

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge, there is no support for WebRTC on iOS browsers. If you want to use WebRTC on iOS you will need a native application. In particular, in order to build a native iOS app with TokBox, including real-time communication with functionalities like Audio/Video call, text chatting, screen sharing and annotation you can find it at:

https://github.com/opentok/one-to-one-sample-apps

https://github.com/opentok/textchat-acc-pack

https://github.com/opentok/screensharing-annotation-acc-pack